# Prevent other-window from choosing side window

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist

I have recently started using `buffer-display-alist` to sensibly place windows within a frame. Typically, I'll have one or two windows of code buffers that I actively work in and a bottom "side window" that hosts shell and test buffers. My configuration looks like this:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(display-buffer-alist
   (quote
    (("\\*eshell"
      (display-buffer-in-side-window)
      (side . bottom)
      (slot . -1))
     ("\\*shell"
      (display-buffer-in-side-window)
      (side . bottom)
      (slot . -1))
     ...
```

I *had* a now-lost configuration that prevented `other-window` (i.e. `C-x o`) from ever setting the bottom "side window" as the active window. If I wanted to interact with that window, I would click into it with the mouse or use some other command (e.g. `windmove-*`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer in [the documentation for Frame Layouts with Side Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Layouts-with-Side-Windows.html#Frame-Layouts-with-Side-Windows).

Ultimately, I needed to set the [`no-other-window` window parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Parameters.html#index-ignore_002dwindow_002dparameters-2976) in my side windows. [`display-buffer-in-side-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Buffers-in-Side-Windows.html#Displaying-Buffers-in-Side-Windows) accepts a list of arbitrary window parameters to be set on the resultant window by way of a `window-parameter` alist element.

My resulting code/configuration looks like this:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(display-buffer-alist
   '(("\\*eshell" display-buffer-in-side-window
      (side . bottom)
      (slot . -1)
      (window-parameters . ((no-other-window . t)))))))
```

Comment: If the answer has solved the problem, you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it - and yes, accepting your own answer is allowed!